# Call activity.setLocalNightMode before activity.onCreate() leads to inconsistent resources / colors

Tags: android, androidx

We want to set the `localNightMode` of an activity before the activity is created, to avoid an activity restart.

Therefore, in the `onCreate` we call:

```
delegate.localNightMode = NIGHT
delegate.applyDayNight()
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```

This works. Mostly. For some reason, sometimes, some resources use the color values from the day instead of the night values. So our app is in night, but 1-2 texts or a drawable use the wrong color. This is fixed with the next activity restart (rotation, activity resume, etc.)

If we switch the order in the `onCreate`:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
delegate.localNightMode = NIGHT
delegate.applyDayNight()
```

our activity restarts immediately during the creation. You see the day style for half a second, then it switches to night mode. Then everything is correct.

We have tried with our without `delegate.applyDayNight()`. The `delegate.applyDayNight()` helps, but does not fix the issue.

Do you have any idea what might be wrong? Do we need to call something else?